# Where is /root/anaconda3?

Tags: linux, anaconda, root, opensuse

I installed Anaconda3 and it should be located in the `/root/anaconda3` folder. I can't find it using the search tab (I'm using the OpenSUSE Leap 15.4 operating system). How can I access this?

Answer (score 2):

Most probably it has been put in another directory, you can search it using:

```
find / -name "anaconda3"
```

Or:

```
sudo find / -name "anaconda3"
```

The last might be interesting in case you need to search within directories where you don't have permission.